# In reportNG path is displayed instead of pic

Tags: selenium, webdriver, reportng

after failing the test case using myeventlistner, i m able to take screenshot but at reportNG i am getting path instead of pic.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to insert some fragment of HTML into the ReportNG report so that it shows a picture?

By default ReportNG will escape log entries to avoid mark-up problems.  But if you are sure this is what you want to do and that it won't cause problems elsewhere then you can turn off the escaping by setting the `org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output` property to `false`.